# SQL Query Returns different results based on the number of columns selected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello
I am writing a query and am little confused about the results i'm getting.

select distinct(serial_number)
from AssyQC

This query returns 309,822 results

However if I modify the select statement to include a different column as follows

select distinct(serial_number), SCAN_TIME
from AssyQC

The query returns 309,827 results. The more columns I add the more results show up.

I thought the results would be bound to only the distinct serial_number that were returned initially. That is what I want, only the distinct serial_numbers

Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Select distinct but return all columns ???](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-select-distinct-but-return-all-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT distinct` applies to the whole selected column list not just `serial_number`.

The more columns you add then clearly the more unique combinations you are getting.

**Edit**

From your comment on Cade's answer

> let's say i wanted the largest/latest
>   time stamp

this is what you neeed.

```
SELECT serial_number, MAX(SCAN_TIME) AS SCAN_TIME
FROM AssyQC
GROUP BY serial_number
```

Or if you want additional columns

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY serial_number 
                              ORDER BY SCAN_TIME DESC) AS RN
FROM AssyQC
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: It looks at the values in all the selected columns when removing duplicates. Putting parentheses in the query has no effect.

Comment: OK, I understand now. I guess I assumed since I typed it such as distinct(serial_number) with the parenthesis it would only apply to that serial number column

Comment: @AFJ - So what did you want to be returned for the other columns? Presumably 5 of the `serial_number` values have more than one `SCAN_TIME` from the numbers in your question (or possibly 1 might have 5 `scan_times` etc)

Answer (score 0):

you're probably looking for

```
select distinct on serial_number serial_number, SCAN_TIME from AssyQC
```

See this related question:

[SQL/mysql - Select distinct/UNIQUE but return all columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-select-distinct-but-return-all-columns/6127471#6127471)