# How to get more column values along with distinct column in the Oracle database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How to get more columns along with distinct column values in Oracle ?

```
select DISTINCT cname 
from customer 
where code is not null;
```

I need `cname`, `cvalue`, `cdate` with `distinct cname`

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some sample input data and the expected output from that data. Does `select distinct cname, cvalue, cdate from customer where code is not null;` not do the trick?

Comment: im getting : Ravi 78, Ravi 75 , i dont want duplicate
expected output:
cname   cvalue  cdate
================
Ravi      78       12-02-18
balu      89        09-07-18

Comment: possible duplicate question [ORACLE Select Distinct return many columns and where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778686/oracle-select-distinct-return-many-columns-and-where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not really make sense. `DISTINCT` does not affect columns, it eliminates duplicate *rows*. So if you have:

```
a    b    c
a    b    c
d    b    c
```

Using `DISTINCT` gives you:

```
a    b    c
d    b    c
```

You're going to have to be more specific in the output you're getting and what you want.