# MySQL Query. How to group one field and keep only unique by other field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help with mysql query.

So, I have table like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
ReceivingDateTime   | SenderNumber | TextDecoded | UDH          |
---------------------------------------------------------------
2013-01-31 16:12:19 | +70000001111 | Bla-bla-bla | 050003A70201 |
2013-01-31 16:12:19 | +70000001111 | Bla-bla-bla | 050003A70202 |
2012-01-20 19:24:21 | +70000001111 | Bla-bla-bla |              |
2012-01-18 14:14:19 | +70000002222 | Bla-bla-bla |              |
2012-01-21 13:12:20 | +70000002222 | Bla-bla-bla |              |
2012-01-15 17:12:10 | +70000003333 | Bla-bla-bla | 050003DC0201 |
2012-01-15 17:13:18 | +70000003333 | Bla-bla-bla | 050003DC0202 |
```

And now my query is

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(TextDecoded SEPARATOR '') TextDecoded,
`ID` 
FROM `inbox`
GROUP BY IF(UDH='',id,SUBSTR(UDH,1,10)) ORDER by `ReceivingDateTime` DESC;
```

**Question**

It works almost fine, but I wanna see something like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
ReceivingDateTime   | SenderNumber | TextDecoded            |
-------------------------------------------------------------
2013-01-31 16:12:19 | +70000001111 | Bla-bla-blaBla-bla-bla |
2012-01-21 13:12:20 | +70000002222 | Bla-bla-bla            |
2012-01-15 17:12:10 | +70000003333 | Bla-bla-blaBla-bla-bla |
```

How I think it should work: Group TextDecoded by UDH, sort by Date, keep only unique SenderNumber which newer than other same SenderNumber. (maybe it's wrong). Sorry for my French.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking can you add more brief

Comment: what is the `id` column?

Comment: I don't know will you understand me or not, but I will try to explain. Lets see on iPhone messages, you see only newest message on screen, but when you click on that, there is more. In my case almost same. Even if you will look to Mail.app on Mac OS, all messages grouped by sender. You got it? or need more explanation?:)

Comment: BhupeshC, I don't know:D lol. I just copied that from another topic and it's work fine for me. Try to do new query, my is for example.

Comment: I downvoted your question because your query cannot work with your sample data: the `id` column is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
As noted in the comments whilst MySQL in practice will return the data from the first row it finds in the inner query, it isn't guaranteed to do this. To guarantee this then something like the following would be needed:

```
SELECT  
    MAX(ReceivingDateTime) AS ReceivingDateTime,
    SenderNumber,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(TextDecoded ORDER BY ReceivingDateTime DESC), ',', 1) AS TextDecoded,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ID ORDER BY ReceivingDateTime DESC), ',', 1) AS ID
FROM (
    SELECT 
        MAX(ReceivingDateTime) AS ReceivingDateTime,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(SenderNumber ORDER BY ReceivingDateTime DESC), ',', 1) AS SenderNumber,
        GROUP_CONCAT(TextDecoded ORDER BY ReceivingDateTime DESC SEPARATOR '') AS TextDecoded,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ID ORDER BY ReceivingDateTime DESC), ',', 1) AS ID
    FROM inbox
    GROUP BY IF(UDH='',id,SUBSTR(UDH,1,10)) ORDER BY ReceivingDateTime DESC
) tbl 
GROUP BY SenderNumber
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        `ReceivingDateTime`,
        `SenderNumber`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(`TextDecoded` SEPARATOR '') `TextDecoded`,
        `ID` 
    FROM `inbox`
    GROUP BY IF(`UDH`='',`ID`,SUBSTR(`UDH`,1,10)) ORDER by `ReceivingDateTime` DESC
) tbl
GROUP BY `SenderNumber`;
```

You may also want to make sure that the inner grouping query is also getting the order right:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        MAX(`ReceivingDateTime`) AS `ReceivingDateTime`,
        `SenderNumber`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(`TextDecoded` ORDER BY `ReceivingDateTime` DESC SEPARATOR '') `TextDecoded`,
        `ID` 
    FROM `inbox`
    GROUP BY IF(UDH='',`ID`,SUBSTR(`UDH`,1,10)) ORDER by `ReceivingDateTime` DESC
) `tbl` 
GROUP BY `SenderNumber`;
```

This assumes that the 10 character start of the UDH has a unique Sender Number, otherwise you will need someting like:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(`SenderNumber` ORDER BY `ReceivingDateTime` DESC), ',', 1) AS `SenderNumber`
```

Which lists the relevant SenderNumbers in the same order, then extracts the first one to ensure we get the data from the row that contains `MAX(ReceivingDateTime)`

Comment: What's the purpose of the outer query's GROUP BY? You aren't using any aggregation functions.

Comment: It makes the SenderNumber unique. When returning data from a column that hasn't had an aggregate function applied, it just returns the value for that column in the first row it finds for each unique value in the GROUP BY clause. Because the inner query is ordered, this will always be the most recent entry for that SenderNumber

Comment: Why not use DISTINCT? In your case, all other fields will be random when you do not GROUP BY all columns that do not have an aggregation function.

Comment: DISTINCT will return a row for each distinct row across all columns in the result set you can't just specify one column. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-select-distinct-but-return-all-columns

Comment: Your implementation is not guaranteed to work. The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) is clear `You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. `

Comment: That is referring to the ORDER BY in the outer query having no effect. I'm aware of that limitation, hence mentioning the SUBSTRING_INDEX/GROUP_CONCAT trick if the SenderNumber isn't unique over the inner query's GROUP BY. In practice it will always return the data from the first row it finds in the subquery. I do accept that this is not documented functionality and could change in the future, so will posted a correction above.