# Select distinct results, when using with() operator in Yii

Tags: activerecord, distinct, yii

How can I select only distinct records, from relational table, when using `with()` operator in Yii?

I'm getting my models (records) like that:

```
$probe = Probes::model()->with(array
(
    'user',
    'results',
    'results.answer',
    'survey',
    'survey.questions',
    'survey.questions.question',
    'survey.questions.question.answers',
    'manager'
))->findByPk($id);
```

I want to make sure, that `survey.questions` relation returns only distinct records. But it seems, that I don't see any way to achieve this (or I'm blind / not educated enough).

When giving relational table name / alias as array:

```
'results.question'=>array('alias'=>'results_question'),
```

[the `distinct` key is not among those, that can be used in such array (as modifier).](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#with-detail)

I tried very ugly, bumpy way of changing `select` from default `*` to `DISTINCT *`:

```
'survey.questions'=>array('select'=>'distinct'),
```

But this has (of course?) failed:

```
Active record "SurveysQuestions" is trying to select an invalid column "distinct". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.
```

**How can I achieve this (seemed so obvious and easy), if it is possible at all this way (using `with()`)? If not, then -- please, advice how to get distinct records in relational table any way** (other than manually filtering results using `foreach`, what I'm doing right now, and what is ugly).

Comment: Seems that query builder consider distinct as a column. Try to specify fields after it: array('select' => 'distinct id, ..., ..., etc')

Comment: @AndreyMischenko Nope, no change (I'm not surprised). `Active record "SurveysQuestions" is trying to select an invalid column "distinct *"` or `Active record "SurveysQuestions" is trying to select an invalid column "distinct id"` etc. this time! :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set [`CDbCriteria::distinct`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#distinct) to true:

```
'survey.questions'=>array('distinct'=>true),
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, which does answers my question. However, I made the same mistake, as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6127338/1469208). And from [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6127471/1469208) to his question, I figured out, that I mistaken `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`. Knowing this, I managed do solve my problem. Unfortunately, basing on auto-generated alias, which isn't something, that suits me. So... maybe you can help -> [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23304409/1469208).