# Can I force Yii to use particular alias in generated SQL

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii, relational-database, alias

I'm retrieving my records using `CActiveRecord` with a `with()` statement:

```
Probes::model()->with(array
(
    'user',
    'results',
    'results.answer',
    'survey',
    'survey.questions'
))->findByPk($id)
```

I wanted to use `GROUP BY` on `question_id` field of `survey.questions` relation, so I changed above to:

```
'survey.questions'=>array('group'=>'survey.questions.question_id'),
```

This caused a SQL exception `1054 Unknown column`. However, by analyzing attached SQL code:

```
`questions`.`question_id` AS `t6_c2`
```

I managed to find out, that I have to use `t6_c2` alias (auto-generated by Yii?). So, another change to:

```
'survey.questions'=>array('group'=>'t6_c2'),
```

and the problem is solved.

But, then again, alias `t6_c2` seems quite... "unstable" (auto-generated?) for me. Can I force Yii to in this part of generated SQL some other alias, provided by me? Or how certain can I be, that this part of SQL code won't change upon next (some later) generation? Or -- is there any other way to achieve, what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can assign alias to your relation

```
,
'survey.questions'=>array(
    'alias' => 'surq'
    'group'=>'surq.question_id',
),
```

read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail)  and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail) for more info

Answer (score 1):

You can set specific and unique alias for each relation table in a relations method in your model. For example,`"user"=>array(self::HAS_MANY, "User", "user_id", "alias"=>"your_alias_for_this_relation")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (i'm asumming 'survey.questions' is a field of the table probe)

```
Prove::model()->findByPk($id)->survey.questions, CHtml::listData(Prove::model()->findAll(array("order"=>"survey.questions")),
```