# SQL Distinct While Selecting All Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried Googling this but couldn't find anything.  When I run the query below, it outputs 4 identical rows.  So I want to use the DISTINCT keyword to eliminate the duplicates.  But I get an SQL error when I run the query.  Remove the DISTINCT and it works fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT list.`id`, * 
FROM `listings` list 
INNER JOIN `selections` sel
ON list.`id` = sel.`lid` 
WHERE 1 AND `activity` = 'running' 
AND ( 0 OR (sel.`parent` = 
'1') OR (sel.`parent` = '2') )
```

Comment: `distinct` like that applies to ALL of the fields you're selecting. it's not a per-field distinct.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Select distinct but return all columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-select-distinct-but-return-all-columns)

Comment: In addition to the above.  Your sql can be simplified. `WHERE activity = 'running' AND sel.parent in ('1','2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT columns.you
              , actually.want
           FROM listings l
           JOIN selections s
             ON l.id = s.lid 
          WHERE activity = 'running' 
            AND s.parent IN(1,2)
```

Comment: Where do I put the DISTINCT then? 

    SELECT DISTINCT id, title, address ?

Comment: @TheHawk DISTINCT is put first.. it applies to all of the fields.. you shouldn't select a column then * like you did in your query. thats not valid syntax for MySQL regardless.

Comment: @JohnRuddell hit the nail.  The misunderstanding is thinking that `distinct id, *` only affects `id`.  It affects the `*` as well.

Comment: @paqogomez `DISTINCT id, *` is not valid syntax in MySQL, so if the OP is using MySQL that wouldn't work. unless it was specified... something like `SELECT DISTINCT s.id, l.*`

Comment: as is a lot of Strawberries comments ;) many are helpful though