# SQL Group and Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I realize this is just like [SQL/mysql - Select distinct/UNIQUE but return all columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-select-distinct-but-return-all-columns) but I am at a total lose and it's always the way, report needed right away...

I am wanting to get (all from the same table)

First -  Unique AsbestosNumber

Seconds - based on that the last survey date

Last - based on those filtered down results get the highest Risk (First look to see it is has 'A', then 'B' then 'C' then 'D' then anything else

```
select AsbestosUPRN, OverallRiskCategory, SurveyDate FROM TblAsbestos GROUP BY AsbestosUPRN, OverallRiskCategory, SurveyDate
```

but have also tried the below which ive of not be bound errors.

```
SELECT * FROM TblAsbestos  

JOIN (SELECT AsbestosUPRN, Max(OverallRiskCategory) FROM TblAsbestos) As Tbl2
On Tbl2.AsbestosUPRN = Tbl1.AsbestosUPRN   
ORDER BY  Tbl1.AsbestosUPRN
```

I then need to modify the report to also search by a unique number in another table.

Example date:

```
AsbestosUPRN SurveyDate OverallRiskCategory
011203200 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 N/A
011203200 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 N/A
011203200 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 N/A
011203200 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 C
011203200 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 N/A
011203200 2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700630 2014-01-10 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700630 2014-01-10 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700620 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700620 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700620 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700620 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700620 2014-01-15 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700630 2014-01-10 00:00:00.000 N/A
030700630 2014-01-10 00:00:00.000 N/A
```

---

Fixed, working code:

```
select 
    AsbestosUPRN, 
    min(OverallRiskCategory) as OverallRiskCategory, 
    max(SurveyDate) as SurveyDate
FROM TblAsbestos 
GROUP BY 
    AsbestosUPRN
```

Comment: This might be a little more clear if you mocked up a schema with some sample data in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).  Make sure to note expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want the UPRN with the most recent survey date for the UPRN, with the highest risk classification on that UPRN/Date combination.  If that is what you want then the following SQL code should work.

```
WITH md AS (
    SELECT AsbestosUPRN, Max(SurveyDate) AS maxdate
    FROM TblAsbestos
    GROUP BY AsbestosUPRN
    )
SELECT md.AsbestosUPRN, maxdate, Max(overallriskcategory) AS maxrisk
FROM md, TblAsbestos t
WHERE md.AsbestosUPRN = t.AsbestosUPRN AND
    md.maxdate = t.surveydate
GROUP BY md.AsbestosUPRN, maxdate;
```

Note that this will only work if the N/A data is actually NULL in the database.  Otherwise max(overallriskcategory) will always return 'N/A' as it is the 'highest' string.  If you need to convert the 'N/A' to NULL the following should work:

```
UPDATE tblasbestos
SET overallriskcategory = NULL
WHERE overallriskcategory = 'N/A';
```

Comment: Marked as answer as right. What I have done is create a numerical value for the Overallriskcategory to ensure the output is right.

Answer (score 1):

If the AsbestotosUPRN is unique, it can't be all within one table. I assume, you have following table:

```
UPRN    OverallRiskCategory   SurveyDate
   1                2           1/1/14
   1                5           1/2/14
   1                3           1/3/14
   2                7           1/1/14
```

And you want to get something like this:

```
UPRN    OverallRiskCategory
   1                5      
   2                7
```

right?

then, you should work with aggregated functions:

```
SELECT UPRN, max(OverallRiskCategoy)
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY UPRN
```

Comment: Sadly it is not Unique, that would be to easy :-(

Comment: Can you also add your expected result on the sample data? This would be helpful to understand, what you are going to achieve