# select distinct from multiple columns return multiple columns (all columns) PSQL

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I'm trying to do a distinct operation on OHLC data where I have multiple dates per symbol

I can do the operation itself just fine, it only returns date, and symbol

```
select distinct timestamp, symbol from mv_qs_facts group by mv_qs_facts.symbol, mv_qs_facts.timestamp;
```

but I'd like it to return all columns (additional: close, open, high, low, volume) as well.

My goal is to return the last distinct (timestamp, symbol)

an idea I had.

```
select distinct on (timestamp, symbol), close, open, high, low from mv_qs_facts group by mv_qs_facts.symbol, mv_qs_facts.timestamp;
```

I see it's not as easy as this statement.

I've read I might be able to solve it with a subquery, a temporary table, or a join (all which don't use distinct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON ()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (timestamp, symbol)
   timestamp, symbol, close, open, high, low
FROM mv_qs_facts;
```

This will return `close`, `open`, `high` and `low` for a random member of the group.

If you want to control which member is used, add an `ORDER BY` clause, then the first member in this ordering is taken.

If the problem is memory consumption *on the client*, you should use cursors:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT ...;
FETCH 100 FROM c;
FETCH 100 FROM c;
...
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have over 2 million records and this runs out of memory. :...( my hope was to do this in psql vs r to try to avoid memory issues but I see I'm still having them.

Comment: I lowered it to 1 same result.   Is there a way to partition/group by symbol and then do the operation

Comment: That seems unlikely. Please explain in detail: what component is running out of memory? What is the error message? Is there a memory context dump in the PostgreSQL log?

Comment: ERROR:  out of memory for query result

Comment: The keyword is "for query result". I bet it is the client that has problems keeping the result in memory. Try using a cursor and fetch only a couple of results at a time.

Comment: thank you for that advice.  I did a create table as [then your query]

Comment: CREATE materialized view temp AS  
SELECT DISTINCT ON (timestamp, symbol)
   id, timestamp, symbol, close, open, high, low
FROM qs_facts ORDER BY id desc; produces error: "SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions".  So this doesn't allow me to select the last distinct id per symbol, timestamp

Comment: got it! CREATE materialized view temp AS  
SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol, timestamp)
   id, timestamp, symbol, close, open, high, low
FROM qs_facts order by symbol, timestamp, id desc; thanks  @RhodiumToad on #postgresql on irc.freenode.net

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select distinct t1.* from (
select row_number() over (partition by symbol order by timestamp desc) as rn, * from 
mv_qs_facts) as t1
    where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: error "select row_number() over (partition by s.symbol, order by ti..." with order by... I was able to run the subquery (or whatever it's called) without order by and s.symbol (i.e. just symbol) as such "select row_number() over (partition by symbol) as rn, timestamp, symbol from mv_qs_facts".  The whole command works "select t1.symbol, t1.timestamp from (
select row_number() over (partition by symbol) as rn, timestamp, symbol from 
mv_qs_facts) as t1
where t1.rn = 1" checking if it works now.  It still only returns symbol and timestamp.  Which my original command did

Comment: updated, removed the comma in between partition and order by

Comment: added order by to get only the latest timestamp, but this one depends to you.

Comment: the query runs.  But only returns 2 col symbol, and timestamp.  My original query "select distinct timestamp, symbol from mv_qs_facts group by mv_qs_facts.symbol, mv_qs_facts.timestamp;" does the same.  What I want to do is return open, high, low, close, volume columns as well.  I suspect I can add those columns in somewhere?

Comment: i think you need to join again the table on its ID to get other columns.

Comment: well that was my question.

Comment: updated the answer. please try replace 'id' to your actual column

Comment: I might have a major/minor issue.  I set my key to timestamp, date and I find I have duplicate dates... in other words I don't have an autonumber id...  which may or may not be my issue.  I don't know I'd join without that.  on a side note.  I did find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-mysql-select-distinct-unique-but-return-all-columns by garret simpson that looks like it would run if I had id as well

Comment: got it, you don't need to join. you can select full columns. updated the answer

Comment: that returned unique symbols... vs timestamp, symbol combinations.  Truncating down to 1 date per symbol.  It did return all columns though.  Sorry took me so long to respond, I was reworking my table to have id's... which didn't exactly work.  But I don't think that was the issue (my new id column, as they are all nulls)

Comment: I fixed my table to now have an id column.  So whichever method works best.  I am about to try this once more

Comment: It's still returning just 1 symbol and 1 date per symbol which isnt what I wanted. I need it to return all distinction dates per symbol

Answer (score 0):

I [added id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751415/copy-from-csv-into-table-with-id-serial-column-auto-incrementing-psql/57764401#57764401) because I initially had timestamp and date as my composite key but it turned out to be bad with duplicate dates and I needed something to reference to sort by

```
CREATE materialized view temp AS  
SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol, timestamp)
   id, timestamp, symbol, close, open, high, low
FROM qs_facts order by symbol, timestamp, id desc;
```