# How to get Distinct records from SQLITE table in flutter?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter

I am having a table like this.

[image]

I want to write a query in sqlite in flutter to get all the records where id are different. For above table output should be:-

[image]

How should I work this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the word "distinct on columnName" after the select statement like this:

```
select distinct on id *
from table
```

For reference and more clarity check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-mysql-select-distinct-unique-but-return-all-columns) out.