# PHP Search in tags and get results for another table

Tags: php, mysql, search, input

I'm trying to do a search in my TAGS table and get results for the POSTS table. Let me explain:

POSTS table

```
|id|post_id    |title  |content
|1 |post1111111|Title 1|.............
|2 |post2222222|Title 2|.............
|3 |post3333333|Title 3|.............
|4 |post4444444|Title 4|.............
```

TAGS table

```
|id|related_to |tags 
|1 |post1111111|chicken
|2 |post1111111|dog
|3 |post2222222|cat
|4 |post2222222|fish
|5 |post3333333|fish
|6 |post4444444|fish
|7 |post4444444|fisher
|8 |post4444444|fishing
```

INPUT: **fish**

```
Results should be like:
Title 2 - ............. (post2222222)
Title 3 - ............. (post3333333)
Title 4 - ............. (post4444444)
```

My code is:

```
$row= $db->prepare("select * from tags WHERE tag LIKE ? COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
$row->execute(array("%$value%"));

$show= $row->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$x = $row->rowCount();  
if($x){
    foreach($show as $list){
        echo $list['related_to'].", ";
    }
}
```

`Output: post2222222, post3333333, post4444444, post4444444, post4444444,`

`True Output: post2222222, post3333333, post4444444` **after that, sorting these posts with their contents as result**

I realize my code is incomplete and wrong but I couldn't figure out how to proceed. I know it's too long. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: There's no `post_id` column in the `tags` table. Shouldn't `$list['post_id']` be `$list['related_to']`?

Comment: `select like '%fish%'` also returns fisher and fishing. This is why you get `post4444444` multiple times. So either have a more precise where clause or use `select distinct`

Comment: If you want to get the post contents, you need to `JOIN` with the `posts` table.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127338/sql-mysql-select-distinct-unique-but-return-all-columns might help you

Answer (score 0):

To get the post contents, join with the `posts` table.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT related_to
    FROM tags
    WHERE tag LIKE ? COLLATE utf8_general_ci
) AS t ON p.post_id = t.related_to
```